# How to force the input of a variable to be an integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a class `Player` which has a variable `@hitpoints` in the `initialize` method. I have made the variable accessible by use of `attr_accessor :hitpoints`.

The variable is indeed accessible when an instance of the class `Player` is created. However, I would like to allow only writing of an integer to it. As of now, I can assign a string:

```
conan.hitpoints = "Hello there!"
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another common practice is to convert the argument, e.g. using `to_i`:

```
def hitpoints=(value)
  @hitpoints = value.to_i
end

10.to_i    #=> 10
10.5.to_i  #=> 10
"10".to_i  #=> 10
"foo".to_i #=> 0
```

or [`Integer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer):

```
def hitpoints=(value)
  @hitpoints = Integer(value)
end

Integer(10)    #=> 10
Integer(10.5)  #=> 10
Integer("10")  #=> 10
Integer("foo") #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "foo"
```

Note that you don't necessarily have to type check your arguments. Ruby will raise an exception sooner or later if the object doesn't behave as expected:

```
health = 100
hitpoints = "foo"

health -= hitpoints #=> TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Comment: Thank you very much all. Special thanks to Stefan:) That worked out nicely for me. I used the suggestion of @hitpoints = Integer(value).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom setter for it:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :hitpoints

  def hitpoints=(value)
    raise 'Not an integer' unless value.is_a? Integer
    @hitpoints = value
  end
end
```

You should also use this setter in your initialization method instead of instance variable:

```
def initialize(hitpoints)
  self.hitpoints = hitpoints
end
```

UPDATE:

About `attr_accessor`. This method defined both setter and getter method for an attribute. Because you are defining your own setter later in the code, the default one is not needed and may be discarded with `attr_reader`, as suggested in comments by Stefan and Arup.

I have pretty mixed feelings about this though, as if you were working with somebody else, he will firstly noticed `attr_reader` at the top of your class and will think - `Hey, why is it a read_only attribute`? If it is a new developer, it might even cause him to write some nonsense code.

I believe that the code is to show its purpose, hence I would use `attr_accessor` even if it gives me `method redefined` warning. This is however a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Yes that's the way I also thinking.. But why `attr_accessor :hitpoints` is still needed ?

Comment: use `attr_reader :hitpoints` to avoid a `method redefined` warning

Comment: @BroiSatse Go as Stefan said.

Comment: @Stefan - I've updated the answer to put my views on `attr_accessor` vs `attr_reader`

Comment: @BroiSatse on the other hand, a new developer could stop reading once he see the `attr_accessor` declaration, assuming the class is using the default setter.

Comment: @Stefan - true to that. However this setter is not so much different to the original one, so there would be no harm in it. When he assumes it is read-only he might try `instance_variable_set` which will bypass the whole construct. I agree though my arguments are not very strong here, still would use `attr_accessor` though (I see I'm in minority here :) ).

Comment: I think I like BroiSatse's implementation as well. I wish I could check two answers :) This is what I came up with: